# Can I legally sell my own product in my country which is patented in another country?

Tags: idea, patented

I made one product.but after survey,I got that the idea which I used to make my product is already patented in other country.but that product is not provided to customer (market) by them. their production process is still in progress and it'll take mostly 2-3 months to avail that product in market. But right now I have that product. so please tell me, can I sell it in market in my country. I didn't copy their patent but the idea that we are using is unfortunately same...... 
THANK YOU.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it legal to sell patented product in another country?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/14554/is-it-legal-to-sell-patented-product-in-another-country)

Comment: I don't think its an exact duplicate as it allows for some strategic answers, too.

Comment: Is the patent already granted? Or just an application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make reasonably sure that your product is not exported into other countries that have patent protection. I'd suggest consulting a patent attorney. Also to discuss other possible strategic steps.

Other than that, yes. But make sure there really is no patent for your country.